# Mostrar números desde base de datos con separadores de miles en C#

Tags: asp.net, razor, ado.net

Llevo varios dias y no doy con la solución, mi problema es que lleno una tabla utilizando `@foreach` pero todos los números me los trae sin formato, a pesar de que el campo es de tipo `Money` en la base de datos.

Leyendo encontré esta forma: `var sepa = cart.ToString("c");`

Siendo `cart` un número obtenido desde un *query* previo. El asunto es que de esta forma solo se puede hacer uno por uno, y es muy trabajoso y contraproducente, lo que necesito es que a la hora de imprimir dentro de la tabla  `<td>@table.cart</td>` ya se muestre con los separadores de miles.

*Esta es una captura de pantalla de lo que obtengo:*
[image: Esto lo obtengo con un @foreach]

El código de la tabla es el siguiente. Utilizo un `foreach` para listar todo lo de la tabla de datos. Lo que quisiera es que se mostraran los separadores numéricos, los de miles porque no cuenta con decimales.

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sucursal</th>
      <th>Hipotecario</th>
      <th>Consumo</th>
      <th>Comercial</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  @foreach (var table in tabladatos ){
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>@table.sucursal</td>
      <td>@table.hipotecario1</td>
      <td>@table.consumo1</td>
      <td>@table.comercial1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>}
</table>
```

Comment: Hola @Atejada me parece una pregunta interesante, sin embargo, creo que es muy amplia, para salir de dudas, podrías editar tu pregunta y poner un extracto de los datos que obtienes, así como el resultado esperado. Un saludo!

Comment: Acabo de agregar la imagen y el codigo de como genero la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes intentar utilizando el método `ToString("$###,###,##0.00")` de la siguiente forma en los `rows` que desees:

```
    <td>   @table.consumo1.ToString("$###,###,##0.00")   </td>
```

O en su caso, si deseas, poner el formato de moneda en específico para algún país puedes utilizar `CultureInfo`, incluyendo la referencia `using System.Globalization;`

```
    <td>   @table.consumo1.ToString("$###,###,##0.00"), new CultureInfo("es-Mx")   </td>
```

Nota: en este caso `"es-MX"` corresponde a México.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ayudarte de las *DataAnnotations* para tus modelos.

```
public class table
{
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal hipotecario1{ get; set; }
}
```

O también con el formato de cadena `DataFormatString`:

```
public class table
{
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
      public decimal hipotecario1{ get; set; }
}
```

En la vista con *razor* utilizar el template `@Html.DisplayFor()`:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hipotecario</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  @foreach (var table in tabladatos ){
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(tableItem => table.hipotecario1)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  }
</table>
```